# Podman-compose up error freeing pod lock after failed creation: no such file or directory

Tags: podman, podman-compose

I am trying to execute `podman-compose up` on a `docker-compose.yaml` file that has the following content:

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.12
    container_name: postgres
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
 
  pgweb:
    image: docker.io/sosedoff/pgweb
    container_name: pgweb
    restart: on-failure
    links:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable
```

But get the following error:

```
podman pod create --name=Storages --share net -p 5432:5432 -p 8081:8081
ERRO[0000] Error freeing pod lock after failed creation: no such file or directory 
Error: error adding Infra Container: unlinkat /home/mcostant/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/456a5a86b835d0711b6bc739be11ba790908dd82af5af42e2caa2d7a7555c4c2/diff/var/lib/postgresql/data: permission denied
125
podman create --name=postgres --pod=Storages -l io.podman.compose.config-hash=123 -l io.podman.compose.project=Storages -l io.podman.compose.version=0.0.1 -l com.docker.compose.container-number=1 -l com.docker.compose.service=postgres -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres --add-host postgres:127.0.0.1 --add-host postgres:127.0.0.1 --add-host pgweb:127.0.0.1 --add-host pgweb:127.0.0.1 postgres:10.12
Resolved "postgres" as an alias (/home/mcostant/.cache/containers/short-name-aliases.conf)
Trying to pull docker.io/library/postgres:10.12...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob e921d1a3b212 skipped: already exists  
Copying blob 8ce5aee1dc0e skipped: already exists  
Copying blob e921d1a3b212 skipped: already exists  
Copying blob 8ce5aee1dc0e skipped: already exists  
Copying blob 646fad7537c2 skipped: already exists  
Copying blob 031810e72966 skipped: already exists  
Copying blob 394d743e7eda skipped: already exists  
Copying blob 35c3fe60701f skipped: already exists  
Copying blob 345eac34ae3d skipped: already exists  
Copying blob 9902aba11c00 skipped: already exists  
Copying blob cb99800983cc skipped: already exists  
Copying blob 0b81e35d82fd skipped: already exists  
Copying blob b248fa9f6d2a skipped: already exists  
Copying blob 82e199964997 done  
Copying blob 8fddf5141f39 done  
Copying blob 3b525945ad7c done
```

and get stuck on the last `Copying blob 3b525945ad7c done` indefinitely. I tried `podman system prune --all` and uninstalling and reinstalling podman following the instructions present [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/eam/4.2?topic=questions-troubleshooting-tips#uninstall_podman). I had a different error before related to the content of `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid` and found this [github issue](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/12715) discussing a similar problem and followed the instructions in the command, but nothing worked.

Comment: I solved a similar issue running `podman system reset`. This is a destructive action, but I had just that pod in my PC. After that, I was able to create a new pod and a Postgres container on it. HTH.